# +'0' wont give char value of int

Tags: c, string, int, ascii, do-while

I was trying to make this int to char program.  The +'0' in the do while loop wont convert the int value to ascii, whereas, +'0' in main is converting.  I have tried many statements, but it won't work in convert() .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void convert(int input,char s[]);
void reverse(char s[]);

int main()
{
        int input;
        char string[5];
        //prcharf("enter int\n");
        printf("enter int\n");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        convert(input,string);
        printf("Converted Input is : %s\n",string);
        int i=54;
        printf("%c\n",(i+'0')); //This give ascii char value of int
        printf("out\n");
}

void convert(int input,char s[])
{
        int sign,i=0;

        char d;
        if((sign=input)<0)
                input=-input;

        do
        {
                s[i++]='0'+input%10;//but this gives int only
        } while((input/=10)>0);

        if(sign<0)
                s[i++]='-';

        s[i]=EOF;
        reverse(s);
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
        int i,j;
        char temp;
        for(i=0,j=strlen(s)-1;i<j;i++,j--)
        {
                temp=s[i];
                s[i]=s[j];
                s[j]=temp;
        }
}
```

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFkoP.png)

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2wnp.png)

Comment: `EOF` is End Of File. Not end of string.

Comment: You realize `char` is an integer type, right? `char` literals in C are actually of type `int` even. `printf`'s `%c` code is saying "interpret this integer value as the character corresponding to that ASCII ordinal", but it's still an integer in both of your use cases.

Comment: i am sorry, i dont get you. first expression is woking fine which is this { int i=54;
        printf("%c\n",(i+'0')) } but this is not s[i++]='0'+input%10;

Comment: It is almost always never a good idea to add screenshot links, rather you could have just pasted them as text.

Comment: @meivinay
What's your expected output?

Comment: @dryleaf i expect when do while is over it gives my char value of input(reversed)... just like when `' int i=54;
        printf("%c\n",(i+'0'));'` gives me "g" as ouput it should also give me g when i input integer from stdin. than i call reverse() to get real string. everthing is working fine just this expression `'s[i++]='0'+input%10'`.. it should store the value of input integer as its ascii char value in array.. but it is storing the reversed integer value.

Comment: @ShadowRanger What spec says [interpret this integer value as the character corresponding to that ASCII ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537590/0-wont-give-char-value-of-int#comment107098318_60537590)?  I'd expect something like "the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`,and the resulting character is written."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I'm saying what actually happens on actual systems that anyone actually uses. You can nitpick what the standard says, but that's what actually happens.

Comment: I think I see what is going on here.  It seems there is a lot of miscommunication here.  It looks like what you actually want is a program that print the charter represented by the entered ascii code.  To do this, you probably did an internet search for "Convert int to char".  This provided you with the `convert` function which actually takes an integer and converts it into a string (`char[]`) representation of the integer itself.  I've updated my answer to include a solution for what *I think* you were actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your program and it is working for the most part.  I get some goofy output because of this line:

```
s[i]=EOF;
```

`EOF` is a negative integer macro that represents "End Of File."  Its actual value is implementation defined.  It appears what you actually want is a null terminator:

```
s[i]='\0';
```

That will remove any goofy characters in the output.

I would also make that string in main a little bigger.  No reason we couldn't use something like

```
char string[12];
```

I would use a bare minimum of 12 which will cover you to a 32 bit `INT_MAX` with sign.

**EDIT**

It appears (based on all the comments) you may be actually trying to make a program that simply outputs characters using numeric ascii values.  What the `convert` function *actually* does is converts an integer to a string representation of that integer.  For example:

```
int num = 123;            /* Integer input */
char str_num[12] = "123"; /* char array output */
```

`convert` is basically a manual implementation of `itoa`.

If you are trying to simply output characters given ascii codes, this is a *much* simpler program.  First, you should understand that this code here is a mis-interpretation of what `convert` was trying to do:

```
int i=54;
printf("%c\n",(i+'0'));
```

The point of adding `'0'` previously, was to convert single digit integers to their ascii code version.  For reference, use this: [asciitable](https://www.asciitable.com/).  For example if you wanted to convert the integer `4` to a character `'4'`, you would add 4 to `'0'` which is ascii code 48 to get 52.  52 being the ascii code for the character `'4'`.  To print out the character that is represented by ascii code, the solution is much more straightforward.  As others have stated in the comments, `char` is a essentially a numeric type already.  This will give you the desired behavior:

```
int i = 102    /* The actual ascii value of 'f' */
printf("%c\n", i);
```

That will work, but to be safe that should be cast to type `char`.  Whether or not this is redundant may be implementation defined.  I do believe that sending incorrect types to `printf` is undefined behavior whether it works in this case or not.  Safe version:

```
printf("%c\n", (char) i);
```

So you can write the entire program in `main` since there is no need for the `convert` function:

```
int main()
{
        /* Make initialization a habit */
        int input = 0;  

        /* Loop through until we get a value between 0-127 */
        do {
                printf("enter int\n");
                scanf("%d",&input);
        } while (input < 0 || input > 127);

        printf("Converted Input is : %c\n", (char)input);
}
```

We don't want anything outside of 0-127.  `char` has a range of 256 bits (AKA a byte!) and spans from -127 to 127.  If you wanted literal interpretation of higher characters, you could use `unsigned char` (0-255).  This is undesirable on the linux terminal which is likely expecting UTF-8 characters.  Values above 127 will be represent portions of multi-byte characters.  If you wanted to support this, you will need a `char[]` and the code will become *a lot* more complex.

Comment: s[i++]='0'+input%10;  // The main problem is this line/....it is not giving me char value whereas this (i+'0') works perfectly fine.

Comment: @meivinay: It's absolutely giving you a `char` value. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: @ShadowRanger i have linked screenshot of the output in main question . please check,

Comment: @meivinay I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't give you char."  I think shadowranger is trying to explain that char is essentially a single byte integer type. Of course you are getting char. Otherwise, when you printf string, you would get garbage output.

Answer (score 1):

> *The +'0' in the do while loop wont convert the int value to ascii*

Your own screenshot shows otherwise (assuming an ASCII-based terminal).

Your code printed `56`, so it printed the bytes 0x35 and 0x36, so `string[0]` and `string[1]` contain 0x35 and 0x36 respectively, and 0x35 and 0x36 are the ASCII encodings of `5` and `6` respectively.

You can also verify this by printing the elements of `string` individually.

```
for (int i=0; string[i]; ++i)
   printf("%02X ", string[i]);

printf("\n");
```